# No puedo conectar mi formulario html a la base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Les dejo mi codigo del formulario y la conexion..

```
    <? php

$conectar=@mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$conectar) {
    echo "No se conecto a la base de datos";

}else{
    $base=mysqli_select_db('optica');
    if (!$base) {
        echo "no se encontro la base de datos";
    }
}
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$correo=$_POST['correo'];
$telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
$mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];

$sql ="INSERT INTO datos VALUES ('$nombre',
'$email',
'$telefono',
'$mensaje')";


$ejecutar=mysql_query($sql);
if (!$ejecutar) {
    echo "Hay algun error";
}else{
    echo "Datos almacenados correctamente";
}
?> 








    </for`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contacto</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estiloform.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php  include_once 'header.php'; ?>
    <form action="enviar.php" method="post">
        <h2>CONTACTANOS</h2>
        <input type="text" name="Nombre" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre" pattern="áéíóúabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz" required="" > 
        <input type="text" name="Correo" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo"pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{1,5}" required=""> 
        <input type="text" name="Telefono" placeholder="Ingresa tu telefono" pattern="0123456789" required="" > 
       <textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje" required=""></textarea>
       <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" id="boton">

    </form>
</body>`m>
</body>
```

[image: Aqui mis usuarios en la base de datos]

Comment: añade el código de los archivos .php que estas usando

Comment: Te genera algún error?

Comment: No, no la base de datos sigue vacia solo aparece la pagina en blanco cuando le doy enviar

Comment: osea te aparece la pagina web en blanco? luego de que lo envias

Comment: ¿Cómo pasas los datos del cliente al servidor? (Deberías usar Ajax)... Tienes un grave error, mezclas las API  `mysqli` y `mysql` en el código . Esta última está obsoleta , deberías desestimarla.  También se coherente, si las etiquetas `name` empiezan por mayúscula, usa mayúscula también en el POST. Para asegurarte de que los datos están llegando bien haz un `var_dump($_POST);` en el archivo PHP.

Comment: esto es mala edicion osera el error ` </for`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 1):

Tenés tres errores: El primero es que no pasas el nombre de la base de datos en la conexión, por ende no tiene a qué conectarse. El segundo es que mezclas las funciones `mysql` y `mysqli`. El tercero la concatenación en la variable `$sql`.

Prueba con esto:

```
$conectar = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'NOMBRE DE LA BASE');

if(!$conectar){
    echo "No se conecto a la base de datos";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO datos VALUES ('".$_POST['nombre']."', '".$_POST['correo']."', '".$_POST['telefono']."', '".$_POST['mensaje']."')";

$ejecutar = mysqli_query($sql);

if(!$ejecutar){
    echo "Hay algun error";
}else{
    echo "Datos almacenados correctamente";
}
```

**Actualización**: Agrego un cuarto error que es que en el parámetro `name` de tus inputs utilizás mayúsculas. PHP es un lenguaje que distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

**Actualización**: Tomo lo comentado y te digo que realmente deberías hacer una verificación y validación de los datos enviados por el formulario antes de pasarlos a la base.

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene usar esto: `mysqli_select_db`? ¿Por qué no conectas directamente a la base de datos con `mysqli_connect`... ¿No habrás aprendido leyendo viejos tutoriales? Actualmente `mysqli_select_db` sólo es útil y justificado cuando quieres pasar de una base de datos a otra.

Comment: la query que estas ejecutando es altamente vulnerable a sql injection ya que estas pasando los valores directo de como están llegando del usuario; considera usar sentencias preparadas

Comment: Sólo acomodé su código para no cambiarle la lógica. Creo que es evidente que está iniciando con esto.

Comment: Creeria que la concatenacion de la variable `$sql` asi debe dar error, ya que escapa los `[]`

Answer (score 1):

En la consulta sql no pones a que campos de la tabla van a ir los datos. Y al mysqli_query no le pasas la $conectar.

```
    $conectar = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'NOMBRE DE LA BASE');

    if(!$conectar){
        echo "No conectado";
    }

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO datos(nombre, correo, telefono, mensaje) VALUES ('$nombre', '$correo', '$telefono', '$mensaje')";

    $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conectar, $sql);

    if(!$ejecutar){
        echo "Hay algun error";
    }else{
        echo "Datos almacenados correctamente";
    }
```